# Spinner gets Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, error-handling, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

After I set up a Spinner I get the folllowing Error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

I found out, that when I comment out this line:

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner1Listener());

in the MainActivity Class (line 195) it works all fine but then I can obviously not handle OnItemClicked Events for the spinner.

Here is my MainActivity Class

```
package school.joran.trainitknowit;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import school.joran.trainitknowit.fragments.FragmentDefault;
import school.joran.trainitknowit.fragments.FragmentSettings;
import school.joran.trainitknowit.menu.main.mainAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    String navMenuTitles[];
    int navnMenuIcons[] = {R.drawable.ic_plus_grey, R.drawable.ic_library_grey, R.drawable.ic_import_export_grey, R.drawable.ic_settings_grey, R.drawable.ic_help_grey};

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

    final String KEYUserLoggedIn = "keyUserLoggedIn";
    final String KEYUsername = "keyUsername";
    final String KEYUserProfilePic = "keyUserProfilePic";

    public Boolean userLoggedIn;
    String username;
    int userProfilPic;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle

    public FragmentManager fragManager;
    public FragmentTransaction fragTrans;

    private Spinner spinner1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addListenerOnSpinner1();

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_main_item_names);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_title);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call

        fragManager = getFragmentManager(); //Setting Fragment Manager
        fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction(); //Beginning Transaction so the Fragment can be created
        fragTrans.add(R.id.MainLayout, new FragmentDefault());
        fragTrans.commit();

        prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("mainPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

        userLoggedIn = prefs.getBoolean(KEYUserLoggedIn, false);
        username = prefs.getString(KEYUsername, getString(R.string.no_user));
        userProfilPic = prefs.getInt(KEYUserProfilePic, R.drawable.ic_user_template_white);

        prefs.edit().apply();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new mainAdapter(navMenuTitles, navnMenuIcons, username, userProfilPic);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager

        final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened when drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }
        };

        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                    Drawer.closeDrawers();
                    fragManager = getFragmentManager();

                    switch (recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child)) {
                        case 0: {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.nicht_verfügbar, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        }
                        case 1: {
                            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_title);
                            fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction(); //Beginning Transaction so the Fragment can be created
                            fragTrans.replace(R.id.MainLayout, new FragmentDefault());
                            fragTrans.commit();
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2: {
                            toolbar.setTitle(navMenuTitles[1]);
                            fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction(); //Beginning Transaction so the Fragment can be created
                            fragTrans.replace(R.id.MainLayout, new FragmentDefault());
                            fragTrans.commit();
                            break;
                        }
                        case 3: {
                            toolbar.setTitle(navMenuTitles[2]);
                            fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction(); //Beginning Transaction so the Fragment can be created
                            fragTrans.replace(R.id.MainLayout, new FragmentDefault());
                            fragTrans.commit();
                            break;
                        }
                        case 4: {
                            toolbar.setTitle(navMenuTitles[3]);
                            fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction(); //Beginning Transaction so the Fragment can be created
                            fragTrans.replace(R.id.MainLayout, new FragmentSettings());
                            fragTrans.commit();
                            break;
                        }
                        case 5: {
                            toolbar.setTitle(navMenuTitles[4]);
                            fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction(); //Beginning Transaction so the Fragment can be created
                            fragTrans.replace(R.id.MainLayout, new FragmentDefault());
                            fragTrans.commit();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;

                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinner1() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBenachrichtigungenZeitintervalle);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner1Listener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        /*int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }*/

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this is my full error log when I try to run my app:

```
10-10 00:51:54.727    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ Zygote::ForkAndSpecialize : 0
10-10 00:51:54.727    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ zygote get new systemTid : 9565
10-10 00:51:54.727    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-10 00:51:54.729    9565-9567/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=2: interp stack at 0x5a64a000
10-10 00:51:54.731    9565-9569/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: interp stack at 0x5a752000
10-10 00:51:54.732    9565-9569/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ Elevating priority from 0 to -8
10-10 00:51:54.732    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ prepping for JDWP over ADB
10-10 00:51:54.732    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ ADB transport startup
10-10 00:51:54.739    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=4: interp stack at 0x5a85a000
10-10 00:51:54.740    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ JDWP: thread running
10-10 00:51:54.740    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ acceptConnection
10-10 00:51:54.740    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ trying to receive file descriptor from ADB
10-10 00:51:54.740    9565-9573/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=5: interp stack at 0x5d15b000
10-10 00:51:54.740    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ zygote get thread init done
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9574/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6: interp stack at 0x5d163000
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9574/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6: created from interp
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9574/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6: notify debugger
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9574/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=6 (ReferenceQueueDaemon): calling run()
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9575/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7: interp stack at 0x5d26b000
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9575/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7: created from interp
10-10 00:51:54.741    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
10-10 00:51:54.742    9565-9575/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7: notify debugger
10-10 00:51:54.742    9565-9575/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=7 (FinalizerDaemon): calling run()
10-10 00:51:54.742    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=32KB
10-10 00:51:54.742    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
10-10 00:51:54.742    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
10-10 00:51:54.742    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
10-10 00:51:54.744    9565-9576/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=8: interp stack at 0x5d373000
10-10 00:51:54.744    9565-9576/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=8: created from interp
10-10 00:51:54.744    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
10-10 00:51:54.746    9565-9576/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=8: notify debugger
10-10 00:51:54.746    9565-9576/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=8 (FinalizerWatchdogDaemon): calling run()
10-10 00:51:54.754    9565-9577/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=9: interp stack at 0x5d779000
10-10 00:51:54.754    9565-9578/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: interp stack at 0x5d881000
10-10 00:51:54.800    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/school.joran.trainitknowit-2.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@school.joran.trainitknowit-2.apk@classes.dex
10-10 00:51:54.813    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
10-10 00:51:54.814    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
10-10 00:51:54.814    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17267: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
10-10 00:51:54.814    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-10 00:51:54.814    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
10-10 00:51:54.814    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17271: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
10-10 00:51:54.814    9565-9565/school.joran.trainitknowit D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-10 00:51:54.824    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ received file descriptor 48 from ADB
10-10 00:51:54.827    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:54.830    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:54.830    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000B066, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
10-10 00:51:54.839    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:54.839    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x4000B067, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
10-10 00:51:54.839    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:54.839    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000B068, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
10-10 00:51:54.840    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:54.840    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000B069, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
10-10 00:51:54.840    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:54.842    9565-9571/school.joran.trainitknowit D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000B06A, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
10-10 00:51:54.868    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:54.869    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000B06C, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
10-10 00:51:54.871    9565-9565/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
10-10 00:51:54.871    9565-9565/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 426: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
10-10 00:51:54.871    9565-9565/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-10 00:51:54.872    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:54.872    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000B06E, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
10-10 00:51:54.873    9565-9565/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
10-10 00:51:54.873    9565-9565/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 448: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
10-10 00:51:54.873    9565-9565/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-10 00:51:54.877    9565-9565/? D/skia﹕ Flag is not 10
10-10 00:51:54.899    9565-9565/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-10 00:51:54.899    9565-9565/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4109b9a8)
10-10 00:51:54.901    9565-9565/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{school.joran.trainitknowit/school.joran.trainitknowit.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:167)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at school.joran.trainitknowit.MainActivity.addListenerOnSpinner1(MainActivity.java:195)
            at school.joran.trainitknowit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5125)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2289)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:167)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 00:51:55.406    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:55.406    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000B06F, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
10-10 00:51:55.406    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
10-10 00:51:55.903    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:55.904    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000B070, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
10-10 00:51:55.904    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
10-10 00:51:56.403    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ processIncoming
10-10 00:51:56.403    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000B071, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
10-10 00:51:56.403    9565-9571/? D/jdwp﹕ sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
10-10 00:51:56.550    9565-9565/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 9565 SIG: 9
```

Also other important code:

FragmentSetting.java

```
package school.joran.trainitknowit.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import school.joran.trainitknowit.R;

public class FragmentSettings extends Fragment {

    View myView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

fragment_setting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewSettings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGlobaleEinstellungen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/GlobaleEinstellungen"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switchBenachrichtigen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:switchMinWidth="80dp"
                android:text="@string/regelmBenachrichtigen"
                android:textOff="@string/aus"
                android:textOn="@string/ein"
                android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
                android:track="@drawable/switch_track" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerBenachrichtigungenZeitintervalle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/benachrichtigungenZeitintervalle" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/divider" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="school.joran.trainitknowit" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="school.joran.trainitknowit.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me! I searched the Internet for Hours and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spinner is part of your fragment layout, yet you are calling `addListenerOnSpinner()` within the *activity*.  The activity's layout doesn't have this spinner, so when you execute

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBenachrichtigungenZeitintervalle);
```

`spinner1` is null, so the next line throws the `NullPointerException`.

If the spinner is in the fragment layout, then you need to put your Spinner code in the fragment, not the activity.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply, actually at first I tried to put the whole code for the spinner in my FragmentSettings.java but then it said it can't resolve the "findViewById" method and I put it in MainActivity. I just found out that it works when I say myView.findViewById()